# Adding Expiration date property to a site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a site collection that will have sites added to it on a timely basis by a user. We are going to have that user add a new site within that site collection.

The tricky part is that I need to add expiration date field in the wizard, and have that value added to a property of the site. I can then have a custom timer job created which will delete that site when the expiration date is reached.

I am running SharePoint 2010 server and I was able to look at retention policy but I could not find something for a site - the policies I found were for lists (where I could have a list set to delete).

In summary, I am not sure how to Add an expiration date property to the site and have it referenced from the dialog for creating a new site.

Any pointers will be of great help - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Property Bag settings of the site?  They are easy to set and to query.  You could set those using CSOM.  Here's a sample I found in 2013:
http://sureshpydi.blogspot.ca/2013/05/set-and-get-property-bag-values-in.html

Here is Jeremy Thake reading properties in JSOM for 2010 (i.e. should work equally well for 2010):  http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/using-the-sharepoint-csom-api-to-get-a-property-bag-value/

Of course in 2010 you can set / get property bag values in full trust code as well.

Your timer job could now run off of this property bag setting.

Hope that helps.